# Don't understand this Sturm - Liouville problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sturm-liouville

All the SL problems I have seen before had $ \lambda$ in them, so finding the eigenvalues meant finding the values of $ \lambda$. However I don't know what I am supposed to do in the following:

Find the eigenvalues & normalised eigenvectors for $y''+4y'+(4+n^2 \pi^2)y=0,$ with conditions $y(0)=y(1)=0$, where $n$ is an integer.

I suppose I should put it in the SL usual form but I don't know how to deal with the absense of  $ \lambda$.

Comment: Why don’t you just proceed to solving the ode as usual? It might be that this $\lambda$ has been predetermined for you.

Comment: $n^2$ is proportional to $\lambda$ in your case. So you already know the eigenvalues, now you only need to find the eigenfunctions

Comment: So the eigenvalues will be $n^2 π^2$ for different values of n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving an operator $\mathcal{D}(\cdot)$ their eigenvalues are all $\lambda$ such that

$$
\mathcal{D}(y)=\lambda y
$$

solving

$$
y''+4y'=\lambda y
$$

we have

$$
y = c_1 e^{(-2-\sqrt{\lambda+4})x}+ c_2e^{(-2+\sqrt{\lambda+4})x}
$$

here $\lambda = -(4+n^2\pi^2)$  and then

$$
y = c_1 e^{(-2-i n \pi)x}+ c_2e^{(-2+i n\pi)x}\Rightarrow y = \left(C_1 \cos(n\pi x)+C_2\sin(n\pi x)\right)e^{-2x}
$$

so due to the contour conditions

$$
y(0) = C_1 = 0\\
y(1) = C_1(-1)^ne^{-2} = 0
$$

then

$$
y_n = C_2\sin(n\pi x)e^{-2x}
$$

are the eigenfunctions associated to the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as
$$
         -y''-4y'-4y = n^2\pi^2 y,\;\;\; y(0)=y(1)=0.
$$
If you multiply by $e^{4x}$, then the equation can be written as
$$
          -(e^{2x}y)'' =n^2\pi^2(e^{2x}y).
$$

So, letting $w=e^{2x}y$ gives
$$
          -w''=n^2\pi^2w,\;\; w(0)=w(1)=0.
$$

The solutions are $w_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x)$ or $y_n(x)=e^{-2x}\sin(n\pi x)$,